# Uncaught Error: nodebuffer is not supported by this browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, html, file-upload

I want to upload my excel to a web page an parse, I am using xlsx library for the same, after updating chrome to 56 version, I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: nodebuffer is not supported by this browser

Below is the code I am using,

```js
function handleDrop(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  var i,f;
  for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var name = f.name;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;

      /* if binary string, read with type 'binary' */
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'binary'});

      /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
  }
}
drop_dom_element.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Are you using jsZip by any chance? https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/556#issuecomment-279007131

Answer (score 2):

install

```
npm i buffer
```

and in `polyfills.ts`
Add this line

```js
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
```