# how to load shape file in react functional component with react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, shapefile, react-leaflet

I was trying to load shape file to my react app and i used react-leaflet npm for display result in map

i got some demo code [this is the link](https://github.com/TA-Geoforce/react-leaflet-shapefile-v2)
this example is in react class component but i was working on react functional component but some how managed to change code but facing error
**the below is root folder code**

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, LayersControl } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"; 
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ShapeFile from "./SamShape";
export const Mymap = () => {
const { BaseLayer, Overlay } = LayersControl;
const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState(null);
const [ShapeLayers, setShapeLayers] = useState(null);

const readTheFile = (e) => {
let reader = new FileReader();
let file = e.target.files[0];
//  console.log(file);
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
reader.onload = function (buffer) {
  // console.log(buffer.target.result);
  setGeoData(buffer.target.result);
};
};

const onEachFeature = (feature, layer) => {
console.log(feature.properties);
if (feature.properties) {
  layer.bindPopup(
    Object.keys(feature.properties)
      .map(function (k) {
        return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
      })
      .join("<br />"),
    {
      maxHeight: 200,
    }
  );
}
};
const Style = () => {
return {
  weight: 2,
  opacity: 1,
  color: "blue",
  dashArray: "3",
  fillOpacity: 0.7,
};
};
useEffect(() => {
if (geoData !== null) {
  setShapeLayers(
    <Overlay checked name="Feature group">
      <ShapeFile
        data={geoData}
        style={Style}
        onEachFeature={onEachFeature}
      />
    </Overlay>
  );
 }
 }, [geoData]);

return (
<>
  <div style={{ width: "30%", height: "20px", margin: "10px" }}>
    <input type="file" onChange={(e) => readTheFile(e)} />
  </div>
  <MapContainer
    style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100wh" }}
    center={[18.56, 78.76]}
    zoom={2}
    scrollWheelZoom={true}
  >
    {/* {geoData
      ? (ShapeLayers = (
          <Overlay checked name="Feature group">
            <ShapeFile data={geoData} />
          </Overlay>
        ))
      : console.log(ShapeLayers, ";kliko")} */}
    <LayersControl position="topright">
      <BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap.Mapnik">
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
      </BaseLayer>
      {ShapeLayers}
    </LayersControl>
  </MapContainer>
  {/* <ExampleShape zipUrl={zipurl}/> */}
</>
);
};
```

this code is being passed as props in useEffect

```
"use strict";

var _interopRequireDefault = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault");

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true,
});
exports.default = void 0;

var _regenerator = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/regenerator")
);

var _extends2 = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/helpers/extends")
);

var _asyncToGenerator2 = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator")
);

var _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose2 = _interopRequireDefault(
  require("@babel/runtime/helpers/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose")
);

var _react = _interopRequireWildcard(require("react"));

var _reactLeaflet = require("react-leaflet");

var _shpjs = _interopRequireDefault(require("shpjs"));

var _excluded = ["data"];

function _getRequireWildcardCache(nodeInterop) {
  if (typeof WeakMap !== "function") return null;
  var cacheBabelInterop = new WeakMap();
  var cacheNodeInterop = new WeakMap();
  return (_getRequireWildcardCache = function _getRequireWildcardCache(
    nodeInterop
  ) {
    return nodeInterop ? cacheNodeInterop : cacheBabelInterop;
  })(nodeInterop);
}

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj, nodeInterop) {
  if (!nodeInterop && obj && obj.__esModule) {
    return obj;
  }
  if (obj === null || (typeof obj !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function")) {
    return { default: obj };
  }
  var cache = _getRequireWildcardCache(nodeInterop);
  if (cache && cache.has(obj)) {
    return cache.get(obj);
  }
  var newObj = {};
  var hasPropertyDescriptor =
    Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key !== "default" && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
      var desc = hasPropertyDescriptor
        ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key)
        : null;
      if (desc && (desc.get || desc.set)) {
        Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc);
      } else {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
      }
    }
  }
  newObj.default = obj;
  if (cache) {
    cache.set(obj, newObj);
  }
  return newObj;
}

var ShapeFile = function ShapeFile(props) {
  console.log(props, "props");
  var _useState = (0, _react.useState)(null),
    geoJSONData = _useState[0],
    setGeoJSONData = _useState[1];

  var data = props.data,
    geoJSONProps = (0, _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose2.default)(
      props,
      _excluded
    );
  (0, _react.useEffect)(
    /*#__PURE__*/ (0, _asyncToGenerator2.default)(
      /*#__PURE__*/ _regenerator.default.mark(function _callee() {
        return _regenerator.default.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
          while (1) {
            switch ((_context.prev = _context.next)) {
              case 0:
                _context.t0 = setGeoJSONData;
                _context.next = 3;
                return (0, _shpjs.default)(props.data);

              case 3:
                _context.t1 = _context.sent;
                (0, _context.t0)(_context.t1);

              case 5:
              case "end":
                return _context.stop();
            }
          }
        }, _callee);
      })
    ),
    [props.data]
  );
  return /*#__PURE__*/ _react.default.createElement(
    _reactLeaflet.GeoJSON,
    (0, _extends2.default)(
      {
        key: Math.random(),
        data: geoJSONData,
      },
      geoJSONProps
    )
  );
};

var _default = ShapeFile;
exports.default = _default;
```

i can able choose file from input once i select file the browser throws erro saying **Error: nodebuffer is not supported by this browser** i googled the error but no use if anyone out there who had solved same issue pleas let me know I would really appreciate it

Comment: The error can be found on the internet.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997027/uncaught-error-nodebuffer-is-not-supported-by-this-browser

To be able to get better help, you will need to format your code so that it is actually readable. 
I do not understand the what you mean with the second code part. You will have to edit your question and make it clear what the issue here are.

Comment: i have changed the code format @Disco the problem is my react app (functional component) is unable to read shp files i want that to be load on react leaflet map the example i found in github was this [link](https://github.com/TA-Geoforce/react-leaflet-shapefile-v2) class component and i tried convert it to functional component here i got a catch shp file not being load i dont know what went wrong if have any solution i'd appreciate

Comment: I would recommend rewriting SamShape, it is unreadable and not really how a react component should be written. It should look more like the example you link
https://github.com/TA-Geoforce/react-leaflet-shapefile-v2/blob/master/src/ShapeFile.js
You need to explain where the error occurs, is it when you try to read the file or when you try to convert it to a geoJson?

Comment: Samshape is the second code snippet which copy from [this link](https://github.com/TA-Geoforce/react-leaflet-shapefile-v2/blob/master/src/ShapeFile.js)of lib folder shapefile.sj
the error occure when i select .shp file from device the browser throws error node buffer by this browser

Comment: i tried npm buffer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997027/uncaught-error-nodebuffer-is-not-supported-by-this-browser] but i could not find polyfills.ts to add the  code