# Loading shape file on React Leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

i have requirement where i need to load .shp,shx,qml, Shapefile  on react-leaflet map in react functional component the loading has to be done by user where user has option to choose shape file from his device

i have tried this functional component  https://codesandbox.io/s/add-zipped-shapefiles-to-a-react-leaflet-map-e7cr0?file=/src/Shapefile.jsx  this example it works but i need  react functional component example where have option to choose shp file from his device

**if anyone know or has done this let me know this would mean a lot to me**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The example is made of functional components. Looks like this is not a Leaflet issue, you just need to figure out how to upload and store a file? 
There is tones of packages that help you with fileuploads, but can also be done with just a input tag 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: i can upload using input tag but how can i  read the shp data and display it on leaflet map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickest (and maybe a bit rush) solution to achieve what you want is to use the shapefile reader and converter from this guy [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kg0q1) and adjust the codesandbox to be able to load the file via input file like this:

The sandbox I embedded uses a function called `extractShapes` which will convert the shapefile to geojson. After that it will be easy for you to manage it using Leaflet and react-leaflet. Once you read the file via the input file you store it in a variable and then you can pass it down to Map and Shapefile comp respetively. Also show the map once the file is loaded.

App.js

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = async (e) => {
    setData(await extractShapes(e.target.files));
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      {data && <Leaflet data={data} />}
    </>
  );
}
```

You pass the data via prop drilling on Leaflet component and then you get them on the `Shapefile` component. You can use a state management lib to refactor this or context api even better. Another possible refactor could be to find a lib or a way to shorten the convert implementation. I just googled and found that in a few minutes.

```
Shapefile({ data }) {
  const map = useMap();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data || !map) return;

    const geo = L.geoJson(
      { features: [] },
      {
        onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
          var out = [];
          if (f.properties) {
            for (var key in f.properties) {
              out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
            }
            l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
          }
        }
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    geo.addData(data); // only this line will change from 3 lines to 1
  }, [map, data]);

  return null;
}
```

Note that I have upgraded my codesandbox to all the latest versions of all packages and only tried it with the current existing file there (TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip). You can play and adjust it to your needs from that point. I think you have the big picture now.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-shape-file-on-react-leaflet-b2d156?file=/src/App.js:106-119)

Comment: hey thanks for tour suggestion i tried same demo in my react app i throws error nodebuffer not supported by browser this error because in (utils.js file  we use buffer ) i goggled error got this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997027/uncaught-error-nodebuffer-is-not-supported-by-this-browser) but i dont  find polifills.ts in my app my react version is: ^17.0.2, react-leaflet": "^3.2.5 where i went wrong

Comment: You re welcome. But this is project specific otherwise works as expected

Comment: the code is throwing error saying like**nodebuffer is  not supported by this browser ** how to over come this problem

Comment: The code in your project my friend is throwing that error. How can I help you if I don't have this code? It is a different topic not related to this question

Comment: i use that above demo code and got error ,so i was wondering if you know anything about this error that  would be really helpful

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: okay it got resolved ,thank you so much for guidance and example codes it helped ah lot

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your issue. Read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you are new to SO